# How to display hash table's values by delivering a array consist of hash table's keys in powershell?

Tags: powershell

```
$hash = @{}
$hash.x1 = 1
$hash.x2 = 2
```

Can I display the hash table's values like this?

```
$hash.[x1,x2]
```

Comment: Why not just $hash.Values? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What Matthias said. But to answer your question: no, that wouldn't work, but `$hash['x1','x2']` would.

Comment: because I don't want to get all values of the hash table.This is a example.

Comment: You can provide a string array as a key. `$array = 'x1','x2'; $hash[$array]`

Comment: @AdamMnich  You are totally right.Thank you

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers You should add that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$hash.[x1,x2]` (with dot and bare words) will not work, but you can use the [index operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about_operators?view=powershell-3.0) directly on a hashtable with an array of the key names (as strings). Like this:

```
$hash['x1','x2']
```

or like this:

```
$keys = 'x1', 'x2'
$hash[$keys]
```